# problems hosting a website with github, domain managed with namecheap

Tags: web, github, hosting

I'm trying to host a website using github.com. I CName-ed my website (lclu.ca managed with namecheap.com) on GitHub. I put the host name, @ for url redirect as 204.232.175.78  on namecheap, as instructed by several tutorials. I also put host name, www cname as liuchenlu.github.io.
When i go on lclu.ca, I get a 404 github page not found! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Website hosting issues are off topic

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong! I asked namecheap to redirect to the IP address when I should've made the record "A (Address)"